# Need help with else if statement

Tags: conditional-tags

I am trying to set up my blog so that there are different colors for 2 different categories, however, if there is a post that is tagged with neither of these 2 categories I want it to default to green.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php if ( in_category( 'News' )) : ?>
    <div class="green">
    <?php elseif ( in_category('Blog')) : ?>
    <div class="orange">
    <?php endif; ?>
```

So basically I want to change it so that if the post isn't in the "News" or the "Blog" category, it will just default to the "green" class.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with PHP, but if you want a default color ( assuming the code below already works ) you could do:

```
<?php if ( in_category( 'News' )) : ?>
    <div class="green">
<?php elseif ( in_category('Blog')) : ?>
    <div class="orange">
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="pink">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you use [`post_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) for this. The following goes into your `functions.php`:

```
function category_name_post_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
        $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    foreach( $categories as $category)
        $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
        return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'category_name_post_class');
```

Your div now looks like this:

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

which output some thing like:

```
<div class="your-category-name">
```

the styling is done via CSS as always.